# Concurrency in gopkg.in/mgo.v2 (Mongo, Go)

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

I wish to use MongoDB in webapp written in Go.

Can I have one `mgo.Session` and use it concurrently in web app. e.g. in `http.Handler`

or should I call `Session.Copy` and `Session.Close` -> make pool of sessions.

It sounds contradictory somewhere I read that pool is already implemented inside of `mgo.Session` and I can use session concurrently and in other places I read that I need `Copy` and `Close`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [`mgo.Session`](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2#Session) is safe for concurrent use. Quoting from its doc:

> All Session methods are concurrency-safe and may be called from multiple goroutines.

But this doesn't mean you should not create and use more of them in parallel, by calling [`Session.Copy()`](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2#Session.Copy) or [`Session.Clone()`](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2#Session.Clone), on the initial session obtained at dial time.

Being concurrency-safe and having benefit from using more of them do not exclude each other (they are not *mutually exclusive*). While you may use a single `mgo.Session` from arbitrary number of goroutines, that will not scale well, that will not scale *at all*. Sessions automatically manage a pool of connections, maybe even to multiple server nodes, but if you're using a single `Session`, you're not taking advantage of that. By creating a new `Session` at the start of each of your request (if needed), and properly closing it at the end (with [`Session.Close()`](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2#Session.Close); preferably called using `defer`), you are taking advantage of potentially using multiple connections at the same time, possibly to multiple server nodes (if available), and thus better utilizing server resources; and getting faster response times (both from the database, and ultimately to your HTTP end users). Calling `Session.Close()` does not close the underlying connection to the server, it will just put the connection back to the pool, ready to be picked up by  another session.

Also see related question about the use of `Session`s: [mgo - query performance seems consistently slow (500-650ms)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40999637/mgo-query-performance-seems-consistently-slow-500-650ms/41000876#41000876)

Answer (score 4):

Calling `Dial` or `DialWithTimeout` or `DialWithInfo` will establish the connection pool. If you need more than one session then you need to call session.Copy() or session.New(), session.Copy() is preferred since it will retain the auth. Here is an example:

Lets say you have a `UserService` struct to handle all your user db needs. Note this is from the top of my head so there might be a few syntax errors but the idea is there.

```
type Userservice struct {
    DB *mgo.Session
}

func (s *Userservice) Create(u *User) error {
    sessionCopy := s.DB.Copy()
    defer sessionCopy.Close()

    db := sessionCopy.DB("test_db")
    col := db.C("users")

    if err := col.Insert(u); err != nil {
        return err
    }
}
```