# too many open files in mgo go server

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, go, mgo

I'm getting these errors in the logs:

> Accept error: accept tcp [::]:80: accept4: too many open files;

for a mongodb server on ubuntu, written in go using mgo. They start appearing after it's been running for about a day.

code:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "io"
    "net/http"

    "gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson"
)

var (
    Database *mgo.Database
)

func hello(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    io.WriteString(w, "hello")
}

func setTile(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    var requestJSON map[string]interface{}
    err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&requestJSON)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), 400)
        return
    }

    collection := Database.C("tiles")

    if requestJSON["tileId"] != nil {
        query := bson.M{"tileId": requestJSON["tileId"]}
        collection.RemoveAll(query)
        collection.Insert(requestJSON)

        w.WriteHeader(200)
        w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
        js, _ := json.Marshal(map[string]string{"result": "ok"})
        w.Write(js)
    } else {
        w.WriteHeader(200)
        w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
        w.Write(js)
    }
}

func getTile(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    var requestJSON map[string]interface{}
    err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&requestJSON)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), 400)
        return
    }

    collection := Database.C("tiles")

    var result []map[string]interface{}

    if requestJSON["tileId"] != nil {
        query := bson.M{"tileId": requestJSON["tileId"]}
        collection.Find(query).All(&result)
    }

    if len(result) > 0 {
        w.WriteHeader(200)
        w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
        js, _ := json.Marshal(result[0])
        w.Write(js)
    } else {
        w.WriteHeader(200)
        w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
        js, _ := json.Marshal(map[string]string{"result": "tile id not found"})
        w.Write(js)
    }
}

func main() {
    session, _ := mgo.Dial("localhost")
    Database = session.DB("mapdb")

    mux := http.NewServeMux()
    mux.HandleFunc("/", hello)
    mux.HandleFunc("/setTile", setTile)
    mux.HandleFunc("/getTile", getTile)
    http.ListenAndServe(":80", mux)
}
```

Is there something in there that needs closing? Or is it structured wrong in some way?

There seems to be lots of places to set the open file limits, so i'm not sure how to find out what the limits actually are. But it seems like increasing the limit isn't the problem anyway, surely something is being opened on every request and not closed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not how you store and use a MongoDB connection in Go.

You have to store an [`mgo.Session`](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2#Session), not an [`mgo.Database`](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2#Database) instance. And whenever you need to interact with the MongoDB, you acquire a copy or a clone of the session (e.g. with [`Session.Copy()`](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2#Session.Copy) or [`Session.Clone()`](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2#Session.Clone)), and you close it when you don't need it (preferable using a `defer` statement). This will ensure you don't leak connections.

You also *religiously* omit checking for errors, please don't do that. Whatever returns an `error`, do check it and act on it properly (the least you can do is print / log it).

So basically what you need to do is something like this:

```
var session *mgo.Session

func init() {
    var err error
    if session, err = mgo.Dial("localhost"); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}

func someHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    sess := session.Copy()
    defer sess.Close() // Must close!

    c := sess.DB("mapdb").C("tiles")
    // Do something with the collection, e.g.
    var tile bson.M
    if err := c.FindId("someTileID").One(&result); err != nil {
        // Tile does not exist, send back error, e.g.:
        log.Printf("Tile with ID not found: %v, err: %v", "someTileID", err)
        http.NotFound(w, r)
        return
    }
    // Do something with tile
}
```

See related questions:

[mgo - query performance seems consistently slow (500-650ms)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40999637/mgo-query-performance-seems-consistently-slow-500-650ms/41000876#41000876)

[Concurrency in gopkg.in/mgo.v2 (Mongo, Go)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42492020/concurrency-in-gopkg-in-mgo-v2-mongo-go/42495522#42495522)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing:

```
defer r.Body.Close()
```

Make sure it is used before return statement.