# Insert a slice result JSON into MongoDB

Tags: json, mongodb, go, slice, mgo

I'm using the `mgo` driver for MongoDB, with the Gin framework.

```
type  Users struct {
    User_id *string  `json:"id user" bson:"id user"`
    Images  []string `json:"images" bson:"images"`
}
```

I have this function which tries to convert the slice into JSON.

The slice here is `UsersTotal`

```
func GetUsersApi(c *gin.Context) {

    UsersTotal, err := GetUsers()

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error:", err)
    }

    c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{
        "Count Users": len(UsersTotal),
        "Users Found ": UsersTotal,
    })


    session, err := mgo.Dial(URL)
    if err == nil {
        fmt.Println("Connection to mongodb established ok!!")
        cc := session.DB("UsersDB").C("results")

        err22 := cc.Insert(&UsersTotal)
        if err22 != nil {
            fmt.Println("error insertion ", err22)
        }
    }
    session.Close()
   }
```

Running it I get the following error:

`error insertion  Wrong type for documents[0]. Expected a object, got a array.`

Comment: does `GetUsers` return `[]Users, error`?

Comment: yes @Hadi , it returns an `array of Users` with an `error` to check , my problem is when inserting this `slice: UsersTotal` into my `mongoDB`

Comment: Hmm, please iterate over your array and then insert each of them. I think it'll work.

Comment: @Hadi you mean  like doing a range on the slice and try to iterate  on each row, it sounds to will effect on the runtime , i am handling with a huge result here

Comment: did that work for you @Data_Geek ?

Comment: @icza could you please give a help here ??

Comment: `MongoDB` is a document-oriented database which simply means you have to provide a document. What you are trying to do here is to insert an array of documents(https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insertMany/). Maybe `mgo` has an api for dealing with this situation.

Comment: @Hadi yes i tried it , it works but here i meant to find a better why in using the package not a hard coded  looping

Comment: Additionally `mgo` is unmaintained https://github.com/go-mgo/mgo#this-is-unmaintained

Comment: try this `cc.Insert(UsersTotal...)` @Data_Geek

Comment: @AndreiSimionescu , clearly  i am trying to move on into golabsign as an updated mgo [globalsign](https://github.com/globalsign/mgo)

Comment: @Hadi aleardy done  i got this error : ` cannot use UsersTotal (type []Users) as type []interface {} in argument to cc.Insert`

Comment: @Data_Geek see https://golang.org/doc/faq#convert_slice_of_interface

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inserting multiple documents is the same as inserting a single one because the [`Collection.Insert()`](https://godoc.org/github.com/globalsign/mgo#Collection.Insert) method has a variadic parameter:

```
func (c *Collection) Insert(docs ...interface{}) error
```

One thing you should note is that it expects `interface{}` values. Value of any type qualifies "to be" an `interface{}`. Another thing you should note is that only the slice type `[]interface{}` qualifies to be `[]interface{}`, a user slice `[]User` does not. For details, see [Type converting slices of interfaces in go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12753805/type-converting-slices-of-interfaces-in-go)

So simply create a copy of your users slice where the copy has a type of `[]interface{}`, and that you can directly pass to `Collection.Insert()`:

```
docs := make([]interface{}, len(UsersTotal))
for i, u := range UsersTotal {
    docs[i] = u
}

err := cc.Insert(docs...)
// Handle error
```

Also please do not connect to MongodB in your handler. Do it once, on app startup, store the global connection / session, and clone / copy it when needed. For details see [mgo - query performance seems consistently slow (500-650ms)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40999637/mgo-query-performance-seems-consistently-slow-500-650ms/41000876#41000876); and [too many open files in mgo go server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47179890/too-many-open-files-in-mgo-go-server/47180097#47180097).

Comment: @Data_Geek If there is no error, then either you pass 0 documents to insert, or you look for the inserted documents in the wrong place (e.g. another db, another collection etc.). If everything seems to match, please edit the question and post the code you tried (including the error handling).

Comment: ,It was an error database switch , perfectly working thanks for the help :-)